# Check whether an argument of ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax is wrapped in try catch block or not

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, roslyn

I'm trying to write a code analysis rule with roslyn.

Basically, I have to check whether an each of arguments which a `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand()` is created is wrapped in `try catch` or not.

The main idea is collect all `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax` objects of `DelegateCommand` class and check each constructor's argument if the first `StatementSyntax` is `TryStatementSyntax` or not.

Can you help me with getting all `StatementSyntax` from `ArgumentSyntax` ? Or may be you have an another approach ?

```
public IEnumerable<IdentifierInfo> Collect(SyntaxNode rootNode, SemanticModel semanticModel)
{
    ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax[] objCreation = rootNode
                                                    .DescendantNodes()
                                                    .OfType<ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax>()
                                                    .Where(c=>(c.Type as IdentifierNameSyntax)?.Identifier.Value.ToString() == "DelegateCommand")
                                                    .ToArray();

    foreach (var obj in objCreation)
    {
        var args = obj.ArgumentList.Arguments;

        foreach (ArgumentSyntax arg in args)
        {
            var expession = arg.Expression;
            var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(expession).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
        }
    }
}
```

Bellow you can find what I actually compile for searching through:

```
public class Program
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();
    public static void DelegateMethod() { try { } catch { } }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DelegateCommand del1 = new DelegateCommand(() => {try{}catch{}});
        DelegateCommand del2 = new DelegateCommand(new Action(() => { }));
        DelegateCommand del3 = new DelegateCommand(DelegateMethod);
        var barInit = (Action)(DelegateMethod);
        DelegateCommand del4 = new DelegateCommand(barInit);
        ICommand test;
        test = new Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand(() => { });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this PRISM 5 or up? Then you might also want to handle the `DelegateCommand.FromAsync()` variation, isn't?

Answer (score 2):

You start in a good way, but to handle it completely, its required more work.

Lets see in your example what we have

[image: LINQ result]
(The screenshot is from [LINQ debugging feature](http://o.oz-code.com/LINQ_EAP) from [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/))

Here what I wrote is

```
var argsExpr = objCreation.Select(o => o.ArgumentList.Arguments.First())
```

As you can see in the right side of the window, we have a three types of syntax nodes in the arguments, so we don't have a general way to handle them all.

You have two ways to handle it.

1. Write method that get SyntaxNode and according to its type, check if the first statement is a try\catch statement
2. Write SyntaxWalker and visit relevant methods, and there, check if the first statement is a try\catch statement

For example to handle the first case which is `ParenthesizedLambdaExpressionSyntax` you need to write something like this (or by yourself or by overriding the appropriate `Visit` method of the `SyntaxWalker`)

```
public static bool IsTryStatement(ParenthesizedLambdaExpressionSyntax node)
{
    return ((BlockSyntax) node.Body).Statements.First() is TryStatementSyntax;
}
```

This is just an example. In your real code you need to handle all cases.

For the `IdentifierNameSyntax` you need to get the method symbol first:

```
semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifier).Symbol
```

Then you need to get the syntax node from `DeclaringSyntaxReferences` and use span, or you can use `location` of the symbol or any other way (`ConstructFrom` maybe).